# After Effects Multiple instances hangs when rendering using PHP and Command Line

Tags: after-effects, aerender

I am trying to render video from Adobe After Effects using PHP through command line. When i try to render video from After effects render Queue, i can see in Task Manager that all CPU cores are using. i have following PHP script which takes AE template file and render video.

```
<?php
  exec('aerender.exe -project myproject.aepx -comp "Final" -mp  -output video.mov')

 // -mp - Additional processes may be created to render multiple frames simultaneously
?>
```

When i execute this PHP file from command line like

```
php /path/to/above_script_file.php
```

its working fine too. All CPU cores are using and video is rendering.

[image]

**BUT** when i execute same script from browser using WAMP server, rendering starts, all instances get starts but suddenly close and 1 or sometimes 2 After effects instances are running but in hanged position. No memory or CPU is changing.

[image]

These are my After Effects preferences

[image]

**UPDATE:**
When i am trying to render using below command
    aerender -project /path/ -comp Final -mp -output out.mov

its working and using multiprocessing. but when trying to render from web app it show below error message in log file

```
There is an error in background rendering so switching to foreground rendering after 0 frames completed out of total 601 frames.
```

Message interpretation:[enter link description here](https://myleniumerrors.com/tag/cs4/page/54/)

```
The multiprocessing feature was unable to use all instances beyond a     certain point in the rendering process. This is an error that only shows     in the render log file.
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try to write the output of your task to a file and tell your system to start it as a background task by adding the &:

`exec('aerender.exe -project myproject.aepx -comp "Final" -mp  -output video.mov >/dev/null &')`

It might also be something in your server setup, the max. memory maybe?